# Distribution of Ti in plm package

Tags: r

I want some basic descriptive statistics of an unbalanced panel data. In Stata, I can obtain "Distribution of T_i", using xtdescribe, which tells the distribution of number of periods for all individuals. How can I get such statistics in R?? Does the plm package have some function to do that? I couldn't find anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get the distribution using `dplyr`:

```
library(plm)
library(dplyr)

data("Gasoline", package = "plm")

# Randomly sample rows to make example panel unbalanced
gas <- Gasoline[sample(nrow(Gasoline), 200), ]

gas %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  pull(n) %>% 
  summary()
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    7.00    9.25   10.00   11.11   13.75   15.00
```

But getting that neat visualization...that will take a bit more work.